# Open url in another application or in browser [Titanium]

Tags: android, android-intent, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am writing a functionality that needs to open a URL either in the another app [if installed in my phone] or else, in the browser.

To open the URL in browser, I can use `Titanium.Platefor.openURL();`

To open the app I am creating the intent.

```
var intent = Titanium.Android.createIntent({
    packageName : appUrl,
    action : Titanium.Android.ACTION_SEND,
    data : url
});
intent.addCategory(Titanium.Android.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);

Titanium.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

I have stuck in below things:

1. How to pass the url to other app to open - I tried passing url using url : 'http://someurl' and data: 'http://someurl' - but didn't help. I got the error: No Activity found to handle Intent
2. How to find out whether the app is install or not? If yes - ask for the application to open, if no - open the url in browser.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the [tag:ios] tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify app is install or not using URL schema with      `Titanium.Platefor.openURL();` method in android. (if app is not installed it will return false).
and for ios there is one method for identify `Titanium.Platform.canOpenURL()`.
and also you can passed something value to application for example if you open google map application with source and destination lat long in ios then call like this

```
var strUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + Alloy.Globals.UserLocation.latitude + "," + Alloy.Globals.UserLocation.longitude + "&daddr=" + dLatitude + "," + dLongitude;
if (OS_IOS) {
    strUrl = "comgooglemaps://?saddr=" + Alloy.Globals.UserLocation.latitude + "," + Alloy.Globals.UserLocation.longitude + "&daddr=" + dLatitude + "," + dLongitude + "&directionsmode=driving";
    if (Titanium.Platform.canOpenURL(strUrl)) {
        Ti.Platform.openURL(strUrl);
    } else {
        strUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + Alloy.Globals.UserLocation.latitude + "," + Alloy.Globals.UserLocation.longitude + "&daddr=" + dLatitude + "," + dLongitude;
        Ti.Platform.openURL(strUrl);
    }
} else {

    var result = Ti.Platform.openURL(strUrl);
    Ti.API.info('RESULT = ' + result);
}
```

one more example.. if you want opening whatsApp application with given message text.

```
var whatsappUrl = encodeURI('whatsapp://send?text=' + msgBody);
    if (OS_IOS) {
        if (Ti.Platform.canOpenURL(whatsappUrl)) {
            Ti.Platform.openURL(whatsappUrl);
        } else {
            Ti.Platform.openURL("https://itunes.apple.com/ae/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997?mt=8");
        }
    } else {
        var isSuccess = Ti.Platform.openURL(whatsappUrl);
        if (!isSuccess) {
            Ti.Platform.openURL("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp&hl=en");
        }
    }
```

Hop this is helps you.. :)
Thanks